Does processed or decrypted evidence pay out more than regular evidence?
In the Houston Breakout heist, you have two objectives: break Houston out of custody, and steal or destroy the evidence in his case (and, optionally, steal everything else out of the evidence locker).
You need to validate at least Houston's evidence in order to complete the heist. If evidence is not Houston's, it changes from Evidence to Optional Evidence, similar to the Syntax Error heist. Does Optional Evidence (evidence that has been scanned and determined to not be part of Houston's case) pay out more than Evidence? Or can you stop scanning once you find Houston's evidence and just toss everything else in the loot cage?

Yes. Based on some testing on normal difficulty, scanned evidence does in fact pay out more.
Here are the payouts I saw on normal difficulty in 4 different scenarios. All of these also included a loose cash payout of $20,000, which I assume is the payout for Houston escaping:

Evidence burnt: $0
Houston's Evidence Only: $80,000
Houston's Evidence + 1 Evidence: $100,000
Houston's Evidence + 1 Optional Evidence: $130,000

Processing bags of evidence seems to increase the payout per bag by 150%.
